# python list not deallocating memory after clearing the element of the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory

I am using lot of list in my long running python script written in python 2.7.
I am using **pympler to identify leaked memory and I found that the list object memory is being increasing**.But I have cleared all list in each iteration.
The RES memory is being increasing largely.After 3 minutes of execution time, the script takes **130 MB of RES memory**,I have cleared all list and deleted all objects that were referenced in each iteration.
I clear list using:

```
   del list1[:]
```

I delete objects that were referenced by using:

```
   obj=demo_class()
   some code
   del obj
```

Pls help me in reducing the RES memory?

Thank you PyNico,I had tried it by removing the references to the object and using gc.collect() manually,but it had no effect.

I am using 4 dictionaries in my script.when **i ran my script using pympler to find memory leakage**,I found that the **size of list object is increasing incredibly.And these list contains the keys of these dictionary**.**Is these list in build implementation of python dictionary?.**

Comment: Without seeing some code that demonstrates the problem, we're only guessing. How do you clear all lists? How do you delete all referenced objects? Have you used `gc.getrerences()` to make sure there isn't a reference to something being held onto somewhere?

Comment: why `del list1[:]`, and not `del list1`?  Using a slice just creates a new list object which you are then deleting.  You are not deleting the original list1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this.It explain why the del keyword doesn't clear the memory -> http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm

You should remove all references to your object then use gc.collect()

Comment: the above link is not working, can anyone please post the answer